# Show and hide confirm password box if something is typed on password box using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-development-server

I want a box that is hidden and  shows itself while  the user types something on the reset password box and that is shown always  when the page loads the password input box.

````
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="inputTitle4">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" value="<?=@$_POST['password']?>">
          <?php echo form_error('password', '<p class="error">', '</p>'); ?>
           <span toggle="#password-field" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye field_icon toggle-password"></span>
          </div>
          <?php }else{?>
           <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="inputTitle4"> Reset Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control rpassword" id="password" name="rpassword" placeholder="Reset your passoword" value="">
          <?php echo form_error('rpassword', '<p class="error">', '</p>'); ?>
           <span toggle="#password-field" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye field_icon toggle-password"></span>
           </div>
          <?php };?>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6 confirm" >
          <label for="inputTitle4">Confirm Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control " id="cpassword" name="cpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" value="<?=@$_POST['cpassword']?>">
          <?php echo form_error('cpassword', '<p class="error">', '</p>'); ?>
    </div>
``` jquery
      $(document).on('input', '.rpassword',function()   {

                $('.confirm').show();
                });
````

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you possibly add some more info, like how what you quoted in code above doesn't work? Where are you stuck with getting it to work? Maybe some quick drawn mockup of how the expected order of things between widgets should be would also help others  to figure out how that may or may not line up with the code you already have.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to listen to the 'input' event on that input, then check the value, if the value exists, you can show the box.

```
$('body').on('input', '.rpassword', function(e){
  if( $(this).val() !== "" || $(this).val() !== null) {
    $('.confirm').show();
  }
});
```

Comment: can you help again ? I need it in a different way If its a new user creating a account then it has to keep the confirm box but if its the old user who wants to change his/her password then the confirm box remains hidden until he/she types something in the "rpassword feild"

Comment: You'll need a flag in your PHP to determine if old or new user. Then use that flag in a condition to add a CSS class onto the form, with that class you can set CSS rules to show or hide the confirm box when the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#password").keypress(function(event) {
  $(".confirm").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
  <label for="inputTitle4"> Reset Password</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control rpassword" id="password" name="rpassword" placeholder="Reset your passoword" value="">
  <span toggle="#password-field" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye field_icon toggle-password"></span>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-6 confirm" style="display:none">
  <label for="inputTitle4">Confirm Password</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control " id="cpassword" name="cpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" >
</div>
```